# Windows 11 App Icons Gone After Upgrade From Windows 10

Tags: windows-11, icons, windows-11-upgrade

A few weeks ago, I upgraded my Windows PC from Windows 10 to Windows 11 (through installation media), but somehow, some app icons are gone. For example, when I open the Telegram app or some other apps, the icons are just gone. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Upgrades from Windows 10 to Windows 11 are not guaranteed.  Do a Windows 11 Repair Install.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11   and Keep Everything.

Answer (score 1):

> I upgraded my Windows PC from Windows 10 to Windows 11  ....  somehow,
> some app icons are gone.

Sometimes the upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11 does not work well. This is not completely uncommon.

**(1) Run a Windows 11 Repair Install**

This is easy to do and can leave everything where you started.

First have a spare 32GB USB drive available.

Then go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download. This will download a file.  Run the file when the download is complete. This will install the files Windows needs for the Repair onto the USB Key.

In File Explorer, see the USB key and run Setup.exe .  This will launch the Repair. Select the option to Keep Everything (which does as it says).

There may be a couple of other prompts, but just allow the Repair to proceed. It is akin to watching paint dry.

When done, see if your Icons are back.

**(2) If not, Reinstall Windows.**

Something else has gone wrong - more serious operating system damage or a damaged Windows User Profile.

In any event, in this case, it is easiest to back everything up and reinstall Windows 11 fresh.